# naming a property with inbuilt definition. Invalid token in class

Tags: c#, .net, class

I created a property:

```
public string fixed { get; set; }
```

It appears "fixed" has an inbuilt definition. So it doesnt allow me to, says invalid token. But I need to create it with the same name. Is there a way, please help.

Comment: use `Fixed` instead. Names of properties should be PacalCase in C#

Comment: no I want it as "fixed" I am mapping the property to jqgrid's inbuilt properties.

Comment: Update: since I assume you use some kind of serializing, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try doing the following:

```
public string @fixed { get; set; }
```

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) says, you can use a keyword as a identifier in your code only with @.

Best of luck!

EDIT

If you want property names mapping, (and I assume you serialize them in some way), you can also

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fixed")]
    public string Fixed { get;  set; }
```

if you use Newtonsoft Json Converter.

(It is also a much cleaner way to handle things)